# How to implement a Global varible in this code, so it can be used in other functions? Using Tkinter and Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

How would I implement a global variable for all the variables in get_credit_score, so that they can be read in advice_to_be_given.

```
def close_window(self):
    self.master.destroy()

def get_credit_score(self):
    monthlyWage = int(input("What is your monthly wage? "))
    monthlySpendings = int(input("What are your monthly spendings? ")) 
    monthlyOverdraft = int(input("What is your monthly overdraft? "))
    monthlySavings = int(input("How much do you add into your savings account per month? "))

def advice_to_be_given(self):
    if monthlySavings == 0:
        print("You should add more into your Savings account. ")
    if monthlyOverdraft == 0:
        print("Maintain not having an overdraft")
    if monthlySavings > monthlySpendings and overdraft > 0:
        print("Spend more money on essentials, instead of putting it into your savings. Ensure that you are not spending too much on essentials, as this can increase your overdraft")
    #if monthlySpending >==3 monthlySavings:
        #print("You are spending too much money in a month, add some money into savings. ")
    if monthlyOverdraft < 0:
        print("Add 15% of your monthly savings into paying off overdraft. ")
    if monthlyOverdraft > monthlySavings and monthlyOverdraft > monthlySpendings:
        print("Cut down on how much money goes into savings, and ensure that your overdraft is being paid off. ")
```

Comment: I suggest instead of globals, you consider `self.monthlyWage = int(input("What is your monthly wage? "))` then you can use/retrieve the value as `self.monthlyWage` in your other instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define them outside the function then use the global keyword inside the functions you want to use them for.

for example:

```py
monthlyWage = 0
monthlySpendings = 0
monthlyOverdraft = 0
monthlySavings = 0 

def get_credit_score(self):
    global monthlyWage
    global monthlySpendings
    global monthlyOverdraft 
    global monthlySavings 
    monthlyWage = int(input("What is your monthly wage? "))
    monthlySpendings = int(input("What are your monthly spendings? ")) 
    monthlyOverdraft = int(input("What is your monthly overdraft? "))
    monthlySavings = int(input("How much do you add into your savings account per month? "))
```

They variables out side the function can be used by any other function when referenced with the global keyword

Comment: Do you have discord so that we may discuss this further? I am having some issues.

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if it helped you with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_credit_score(self):
    Global monthlyWage
    monthlyWage = 2

def advice_to_be_given(self):
    print(monthlyWage)
```

Comment: How would this be implemented in my code? I am relatively new to Python.

Comment: I edited the answer, all you need to do is write Global before the variable name to make it global. the you can assign whatever value you want to it and can read it from other functions.